# set ordering of dynamically registered modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In my application I have one main model, let's call them `users`. I have a module `users` and a submodule within it called `list`.

On consumption of an api endpoint I get 10 users back as an array of users. For each user, I dynamically register a `user` module for each one within the `list` module within `users` using the `id` as the key.

```
this.registerModule(['users', 'list', user.id], UserModule);
```

Then I dispatch some action to hydrate the data in my store. This all works fine.

I have a getter that parses the `list` module(an object that contains `id`'s as keys that point to a `user`) into an array of users. It looks something like this:

```
users: (state) => {
  const users = Object.keys(state.list).map(key => state.list[key]);
  return users;
}
```

#### The problem

When `vuex` dynamically registers the individual `UserModule`'s it orders them within the `list` module alphabetically, not the order in which the modules get registered. This is a problem because I want the array of users to be in the same order as they come in from the api.

#### Example

If the endpoint returns 2 users like this:

```
[
  { id: '3', name: 'Bob'},
  { id: '1', name: 'Tom'}
]
```

Then the list module will look like this:

```
state: {
  list: {
    1: { id: '1', name: 'Tom'},
    3: { id: '3', name: 'Bob'}
  }
}
```

And the `users` getter would then return:

```
[
  { id: '1', name: 'Tom'},
  { id: '3', name: 'Bob'},
]
```

My tentative solution is to inject an order property into each module as it gets consumed then in the getter sort by that order property. It doesn't feel great because I feel like I'm adding a loop to sort for no reason.

### The questions

1. Is there any way to order dynamically register modules as they come in rather than alphabetically by key?
2. Can anyone think of a better solve for this problem beyond injecting an "order" property?

Comment: `No, properties order in objects is not guaranteed in JavaScript; you need to use an Array.` https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/5599288

Comment: right i know they're not guaranteed, but they've been pretty consistent, it's really just the way they get injected to the list module that is the problem

Comment: [Looks like it's about Javascript Object and not Vue](https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/horhggh1/). Numeric property always reordered, alphabet property won't reorder.

Comment: that's really helpful. thank you, actually did a better workaround just storing the ordered array of ids in state, then just mapping those to the dynamically registered module